# Simple PHP calculator

Tags: php, calculator

I'm creating a basic PHP calculator that lets you enter two values and chose your operator then displays the answer. Everything is working fine except it's not outputting the answer to the browser.

Here are the codes for my html and PHP files:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" attribute="post" action="disp_form.php">
<p>First Value:<br/>
<input type="text" id="first" name="first"></p>
<p>Second Value:<br/>
<input type="text" id="second" name="second"></p>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="add" value="add" checked="true"><p>+</p><br/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="subtract" value="subtract"><p>-</p><br/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="times" value="times"><p>x</p><br/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="divide" value="divide"><p>/</p><br/>
<p></p>
<button type="submit" name="answer" id="answer" value="answer">Calculate</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Answer</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>The answer is: 
<?php
if($_POST['group1'] == add) {
echo "$first + $second";
}
else if($_POST['group1'] == subtract) {
echo "$first - $second";
}
else if($_POST['group1'] == times) {
echo "$first * $second";
}
else($_POST['group1'] == divide) {
echo "$first / $second";
}
?>
</p> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 11):

```
<?php 
$result = "";
class calculator
{
    var $a;
    var $b;

    function checkopration($oprator)
    {
        switch($oprator)
        {
            case '+':
            return $this->a + $this->b;
            break;

            case '-':
            return $this->a - $this->b;
            break;

            case '*':
            return $this->a * $this->b;
            break;

            case '/':
            return $this->a / $this->b;
            break;

            default:
            return "Sorry No command found";
        }   
    }
    function getresult($a, $b, $c)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
        $this->b = $b;
        return $this->checkopration($c);
    }
}

$cal = new calculator();
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{   
    $result = $cal->getresult($_POST['n1'],$_POST['n2'],$_POST['op']);
}
?>

<form method="post">
<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td><strong><?php echo $result; ?><strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Enter 1st Number</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="n1"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Enter 2nd Number</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="n2"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Select Oprator</td>
        <td><select name="op">
            <option value="+">+</option>
            <option value="-">-</option>
            <option value="*">*</option>
            <option value="/">/</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="                =                "></td>
    </tr>

</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5):

Personally I would do a switch instead of all this if, else if, else

```
$first = $_POST['first'] + 0;//a small "hack" to make sure its an int but allow negs!!
$second= $_POST['second'] + 0;
$operator = $_POST["group1"];
switch($operator)
{
    case "add"
    echo "Answer is: " .$first + $second;
    break; 
    case "subtract"
    echo "Answer is: " .$first - $second;
    break;
    case "times"
    echo "Answer is: " .$first * $second;
    break; 
    case "divide"
    echo "Answer is: " .$first / $second;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign $first and $second

```
$first = $_POST['first'];
$second= $_POST['second'];
```

Also, As Travesty3 said, you need to do your arithmetic outside of the quotes:

```
echo $first + $second;
```

Comment: You'll also need to do the calculation outside of the quotes. Otherwise you'll just be outputting both numbers with the operator between them, not actually doing the calculation. And put the `add`, `subtract`, etc in quotes.

Answer (score 3):

You also need to put the [== 'add'] math operation into quotes

```
if($_POST['group1'] == 'add') {
echo $first + $second;
}
```

complete code schould look like that :

```
<?php
$first = $_POST['first'];
$second= $_POST['second'];
if($_POST['group1'] == 'add') {
echo $first + $second;
}
else if($_POST['group1'] == 'subtract') {
echo $first - $second;
}
else if($_POST['group1'] == 'times') {
echo $first * $second;
} 
else if($_POST['group1'] == 'divide') {
echo $first / $second;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the values the same way to get the calculator operation which looks like:

```
<?php
if($_POST['group1'] == add) {
echo "$_POST['first']+ $_POST['second'];
}
... and so on
?>
```

Or, to make it easier, just do:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Answer</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>The answer is: 
<?php
$first = $_POST['first'];
$second= $_POST['second'];

if($_POST['group1'] == add) {
echo "$first + $second";
}
else if($_POST['group1'] == subtract) {
echo "$first - $second";
}
else if($_POST['group1'] == times) {
echo "$first * $second";
}
else($_POST['group1'] == divide) {
echo "$first / $second";
}
?>
</p> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$first = doubleval($_POST['first']);
$second = doubleval($_POST['second']);

if($_POST['group1'] == 'add') {
    echo "$first + $second = ".($first + $second);
}

// etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Check string using single quotes

Ex. `$_POST['group1'] == 'add'`

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Calculator</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    HTML Code is here:

         <form method="post">
            <input type="text" name="numb1">
            <input type="text" name="numb2">
            <select name="operator" id="">
               <option>None</option>
               <option>Add</option>
               <option>Subtract</option>
               <option>Multiply</option>
               <option>Divide</option>
               <option>Square</option>
            </select>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Calculate</button>
         </form>

    PHP Code:

        <?php 

            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                $result1 = $_POST['numb1'];
                $result2 = $_POST['numb2'];
                $operator = $_POST['operator'];
                switch ($operator) {
                    case 'None':
                        echo "You need to select any operator";
                        break;
                    case 'Add':
                        echo $result1 + $result2;
                        break;
                    case 'Subtract':
                        echo $result1 - $result2;
                        break;
                    case 'Multiply':
                        echo $result1 * $result2;
                        break;
                    case 'Divide':
                        echo $result1 / $result2;
                        break;
                    case 'Square':
                        echo $result1 ** $result2;
                        break;
                }
            }


         ?>
        enter code here

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

> Make this changes in php file

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Answer</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>The answer is: 
<?php
$first = $_POST['first'];
$second= $_POST['second'];
if($_POST['group1'] == 'add') {
echo $first + $second;
}
else if($_POST['group1'] == 'subtract') {
echo $first - $second;
}
else if($_POST['group1'] == 'times') {
echo $first * $second;
}

else if($_POST['group1'] == 'divide') {
echo $first / $second;
}
else {
    echo "Enter the numbers properly";
}
?>
</p> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hello! welcome to stackoverflow. you might want to explain your code, and what are the changes you've added.

Comment: Add a else part for the if statement. The operation id(add,subtract,...)has to be specified in quotes(''). And the answer has to be calculated and then printed so, the quotes('') after echo should be removed as ('') will print the statement and not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$cal1= $_GET['cal1'];
$cal2= $_GET['cal2'];
$symbol =$_GET['symbol'];


if($symbol == '+')
{
    $add = $cal1 + $cal2;
    echo "Addition is:".$add;
}

else if($symbol == '-')
{
    $subs = $cal1 - $cal2;
    echo "Substraction is:".$subs;
}

 else if($symbol == '*')
{
    $mul = $cal1 * $cal2;
    echo "Multiply is:".$mul;
}

else if($symbol == '/')
{
    $div = $cal1 / $cal2;
    echo "Division is:".$div;
}

  else
{

    echo "Oops ,something wrong in your code son";
}


?>
```

Comment: This is not a good answer. Look here -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Calculator</title> 
    </head>
<body>

    <form method="GET">
    <h1>Calculator</h1>
    <p>This is a calculator made by Hau Teen Yee Fabrice and is free to use.</p>
        <ul>
     <ol> Multiplication: * </ol>
     <ol> Substraction: - </ol>
     <ol> Division: / </ol>
     <ol> Addition: + </ol>
        </ul>
     <p>Enter first number:</p>
        <input type="text" name="cal1">
        <p>Enter second number:</p>
        <input type="text" name="cal2">
        <p>Enter the calculator symbol</p>
        <input type="text" name="symbol">
        <button>Calculate</button>
    </form>
    <?php
    $cal1= $_GET['cal1'];
    $cal2= $_GET['cal2'];
    $symbol =$_GET['symbol'];

    if($symbol == '+')
    {
        $add = $cal1 + $cal2;
        echo "Addition is:".$add;
    }
    else if($symbol == '-')
    {
        $subs = $cal1 - $cal2;
        echo "Substraction is:".$subs;
    }
     else if($symbol == '*')
    {
        $mul = $cal1 * $cal2;
        echo "Multiply is:".$mul;
    }
    else if($symbol == '/')
    {
        $div = $cal1 / $cal2;
        echo "Division is:".$div;
    }
      else
    { 
        echo "Oops ,something wrong in your code son";
    }
    ?>
    </body> 
</html>
```