# Simple PHP Calculator, issues with logic and output

Tags: php, html

Relatively new with PHP, my 3rd day or so looking at it. I've been trying to create a simple PHP calculator that has addition, subtraction, multiplication and division. Wanted to try using this as a starting point: [Simple PHP calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21445245/simple-php-calculator) but I have been having issues getting it to work properly.

//HTML Code

```
<form action="svar_vcalc.php" method="post">
    <p>Tall 1:<br/>
    <input type="text" id="tall1" name="tall1"></p>
    <p>Tall 2:<br/>
    <input type="text" id="tall2" name="tall2"></p>
    <input type="radio" name="gruppe1" id="plus" value="plus" checked="true">+ 
    <input type="radio" name="gruppe1" id="minus" value="minus">- 
    <input type="radio" name="gruppe1" id="multi" value="multi">* 
    <input type="radio" name="gruppe1" id="divisjon" value="divisjon">/ 
    <p></p>
    <button type="submit" name="svar" id="svar" value="svar">Kalkuler</button>
</form>
```

//PHP Code

```
<?php
    $tall1 = $_POST['tall1'];
    $tall2 = $_POST['tall2'];
    $operator = $_POST["gruppe1"];
    switch($operator) 
    {
        case "plus":
            echo "Svaret er: " . $tall1 + $tall2;
            break;
        case "minus":
            echo "Svaret er: " . $tall1 - $tall2;
            break;
        case "multi":
            echo "Svaret er: " . $tall1 * $tall2;
            break;
        case "divisjon":
            echo "Svaret er: " . $tall1 / $tall2;
            break;
    }
?>
```

Now to the issue. It seems like the first 2 cases: "plus" and "minus" ignore $tall1 and purely just uses $tall2. The textstring does not show either for these cases. On the other hand the 2 last cases do what they are supposed to and show up normally.

Ex.
Entering 1 as $tall1 and 2 as $tall2 will give these results:

- case 1: 2
- case 2: -2
- case 3: Svaret er: 2
- case 4: Svaret er: 0.5

At this point I have no clue why this happens and was wondering if anyone else would have a solution? I know that using if, elseif, else would be a possible solution by reworking the php side of the code, but i would prefer sticking to switch, case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats because of the order of execution. In the first case your code if first concatenating $tall1 to the string "Svaret er: ". And then it adds $tall2.
You can fix it by surrounding the math part with parenthesis.

```
    switch($operator) 
{
    case "plus":
        echo "Svaret er: " . ($tall1 + $tall2);
        break;
    case "minus":
        echo "Svaret er: " . ($tall1 - $tall2);
        break;
    case "multi":
        echo "Svaret er: " . ($tall1 * $tall2);
        break;
    case "divisjon":
        echo "Svaret er: " . ($tall1 / $tall2);
        break;
}
```