# Calculator using only php language with only one form input

Tags: php, html

I am creating a php calculator using only one input form. I have tried this much but im unable to do the operations, any suggestion on my coding, so that I get the desired answer.

```html
<?php

if (isset($_POST['select1']) && in_array($_POST['select1'])) {
  $message = "1";
}
if (isset($_POST['select2'])) {
  $message = "2";
}
if (isset($_POST['select3'])) {
  $message = "3";
}
if (isset($_POST['select4'])) {
  $message = "4";
}
if (isset($_POST['select5'])) {
  $message = "5";
}
if (isset($_POST['select6'])) {
  $message = "6";
}
if (isset($_POST['select7'])) {
  $message = "7";
}
if (isset($_POST['select8'])) {
  $message = "8";
}
if (isset($_POST['select9'])) {
  $message = "9";
}
if (isset($_POST['select0'])) {
  $message = "0";
}
if (isset($_POST['select+'])) {
  $message = "+";
}
if (isset($_POST['select-'])) {
  $message = "-";
}
if (isset($_POST['select/'])) {
  $message = "/";
}
if (isset($_POST['select*'])) {
  $message = "*";
}
if (isset($_POST['clear'])) {
  $message = "clear";
}
if (isset($_POST['calculate'])) {
  $message = "";
}


?>

  <div style="padding-left: 200px; margin-top: 100px">
    <form method="post">
      Enter value: <input type="text" name="txt" value="<?php
if (isset($message)) {
  echo $message;
}
?>">
      <div style="padding-left: 110px">

        <input type="submit" name="select1" value="1">
        <input type="submit" name="select2" value="2">
        <input type="submit" name="select3" value="3">
        <input type="submit" name="select4" value="4"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="select5" value="5">
        <input type="submit" name="select6" value="6">
        <input type="submit" name="select7" value="7">
        <input type="submit" name="select8" value="8"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="select9" value="9">
        <input type="submit" name="select0" value="0">
        <input type="submit" name="select+" value="+">
        <input type="submit" name="select-" value="-"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="select/" value="/">
        <input type="submit" name="select*" value="*">
        <input type="submit" name="clear*" value="clear"> <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="calculate" value="calculate">

      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
```

Above is the code what I have tried with. Please can anyone tell me what changes I have to do so that my all operations works.

Comment: Hi Harshitha. Welcome to Stack Overflow. I have closed your question as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/21445245. Have a look at the page and let me know if it doesn't help. I'll reopen the question for you. `:)`

Comment: im not looking what u have give me link please reopen my question

Comment: i'm working with only one input form

Comment: Question opened.

Comment: Quick Questions - Now there's only one input form. How do you plan to preserve what's been given already? HTTP is not a stateful protocol na?

Comment: Are you sure that you have understood the requirements correctly? That seems an odd approach for a calculator (remember, HTTP is stateless). Is it not saying that you can have for example `2 + 5` or `3 * 4 * 5` as data in your input field? When submitting, the server responds with respectively 7 and 60.

Comment: actually what im trying is when i clear any button it should store in the input form ok ,then when i do operation like addition substraction etc it should display me the result.(like in windows we have right same way im trying to create) is their a way to do this please help me out

Comment: @harshithanaik Best thing I would recommend for this is using JavaScript. Not sure why you want to do something totally complicated. `:(`

Comment: actually i have assigned with task to do it in PHP only. i know how to do it with javascript but im learning php so im assigned to do it in php only is their an way?

Comment: @harshithanaik *`there*` not `their`*. Okay, I am not sure if you are understanding the requirement correctly. If that's the case, then you need to explain what happens at every step. Will the answer be calculated for every operation or should it be calculated at the end, when you put `=`? I can, maybe work on it, but might take time.

Comment: the answer should calculate at the end (similar to the windows calculator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many other ways to attempt this, but I fixed the portions of your code that were not working.

You do not need the `in_array()` in your code. Also, you had `"clear*"` where it should have been `"clear"` in the inputs.

You can capture the current `$txt` into a new variable, `$current_txt` and then append the `$message` to it.

It's not a safe way, but you can use `eval()` to do the calculation in the formula. Very easy code injection. Anything in the txt input field would be eval'ed, which would run any command given to it. (Try typing 'phpinfo()' in the input box and press 'Calculate'.)

It would be far better to write a function to do the math by string parsing and output the results.

NOTE: This does not validate the formula. `eval()` will fail if the formula is malformed (ex. `"2++3"`)

```
<?php
// Capture current formula in input box
if (isset($_POST['txt'])) {
    $current_txt = $_POST['txt'];
}

if (isset($_POST['select1'])) {
  $message = "1";
}
if (isset($_POST['select2'])) {
  $message = "2";
}
if (isset($_POST['select3'])) {
  $message = "3";
}
if (isset($_POST['select4'])) {
  $message = "4";
}
if (isset($_POST['select5'])) {
  $message = "5";
}
if (isset($_POST['select6'])) {
  $message = "6";
}
if (isset($_POST['select7'])) {
  $message = "7";
}
if (isset($_POST['select8'])) {
  $message = "8";
}
if (isset($_POST['select9'])) {
  $message = "9";
}
if (isset($_POST['select0'])) {
  $message = "0";
}
if (isset($_POST['select+'])) {
  $message = "+";
}
if (isset($_POST['select-'])) {
  $message = "-";
}
if (isset($_POST['select/'])) {
  $message = "/";
}
if (isset($_POST['select*'])) {
  $message = "*";
}
if (isset($_POST['clear'])) {
  $message = "clear";
}
if (isset($_POST['calculate'])) {
  $message = "calc";
}

if ($message == "calc") {
    // Calculate using eval 
    $current_txt .= " = " . eval('return ' . $current_txt . ';');
}
else {
    // Append input to formula
    $current_txt .= $message;
}

if ($message == "clear") {
    $current_txt = "";
}
?>

<div style="padding-left: 200px; margin-top: 100px">
  <form  method="post">
    Enter value:  <input type="text" name="txt" value="<?php
    echo $current_txt;
?>" >
    <div style="padding-left: 110px">

      <input type="submit" name="select1" value="1">
      <input type="submit" name="select2" value="2">
      <input type="submit" name="select3" value="3">
      <input type="submit" name="select4" value="4"><br><br>
      <input type="submit" name="select5" value="5">
      <input type="submit" name="select6" value="6">
      <input type="submit" name="select7" value="7">
      <input type="submit" name="select8" value="8"><br><br>
      <input type="submit" name="select9" value="9">
      <input type="submit" name="select0" value="0">
      <input type="submit" name="select+" value="+">
      <input type="submit" name="select-" value="-"><br><br>
      <input type="submit" name="select/" value="/">
      <input type="submit" name="select*" value="*">
      <input type="submit" name="clear" value="clear"> <br><br>
      <input type="submit" name="calculate" value="calculate">

    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

EDIT:
Here is a cleaner version of the code using multiple inputs of the same name:

```
<?php
// Capture current formula in input box
if (isset($_POST['txt'])) {
    $current_txt = $_POST['txt'];
}

if (isset($_POST['selectchar'])) {
    $current_txt .= $_POST['selectchar'];
}
if (isset($_POST['clear'])) {
    $current_txt = "";
}
if (isset($_POST['calculate'])) {
    $current_txt .= " = " . eval('return ' . $current_txt . ';');
}
?>

<div style="padding-left: 200px; margin-top: 100px">
    <form  method="post">
        Enter value:  <input type="text" name="txt" value="<?php echo $current_txt; ?>" >
        <div style="padding-left: 110px">
            <input type="submit" name="selectchar" value="1">
            <input type="submit" name="selectchar" value="2">
            <input type="submit" name="selectchar" value="3">
            <input type="submit" name="selectchar" value="4"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="selectchar" value="5">
            <input type="submit" name="selectchar" value="6">
            <input type="submit" name="selectchar" value="7">
            <input type="submit" name="selectchar" value="8"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="selectchar" value="9">
            <input type="submit" name="selectchar" value="0">
            <input type="submit" name="selectchar" value="+">
            <input type="submit" name="selectchar" value="-"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="selectchar" value="/">
            <input type="submit" name="selectchar" value="*">
            <input type="submit" name="clear" value="clear"> <br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="calculate" value="calculate">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it did worked how i wanted. Actually i know how to do using java script but i was assigned to do with PHP only. Anyways thanks for helping .

Comment: Please accept as an answer if this helped you. Glad it worked!

Comment: ok sir i will do that

Comment: sir related to this question i have one small doubt .The suggestion which you gave me yesterday is working fine,but one small problem is  after the evaluation is done if i again press any operation like addition (+), subtraction(-)  its showing error. How to fix this issue any suggestion ?